# For a 0/0 fraction could the limit be any finite nonzero number?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image] 
The answer to this question is 1, -1 and 3 . Not able to understand how is this possible ?

According to me the as x->a the limit only tends to 0.

Thanks

-Ankit

Comment: Suppose that $q(x)=(x-a)^6$ and $p(x)=k(x-a)^6$.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: The limit can be any number in $\mathbb R - \{0\}$, so $1,-1,$ and $3$ all qualify. But it's a strange way of asking the question.

Comment: Use mathjax. [Click on this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @abiessu got it . Thanks 

Comment: @Arbuja Thanks. Usefull